# How to display a selected item in combobox that is selected from database

Tags: c#

I have a combobox with items. I want to get a value from database and show the value in the combobox as the selected item. But it should also display items.

I tried to use combobox.selectedvalue. But it's not working.What should I do?

```
  SqlDataAdapter komut = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Ogrenci where ogr_no= '" +
            Convert.ToInt32(a) + "' ", baglanti);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        komut.Fill(dt);
        DataRow drw1 = dt.Rows[0];
        string ogretim = drw1["ogretim"].ToString();
        //comboBox7.SelectedItem = comboBox7.FindString(ogretim);
        comboBox7.SelectedValue = ogretim;
```

Comment: Not working is not a real error. What is happening ? Last time I checked, `.SelectedValue` or `.SelectedItem` were not broken. Also for your case what your looking for is

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
comboBox7.Items.FindByValue(ogretim).Selected = true;
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' does not contain a definition for 'FindByValue' and no extension method 'FindByValue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you using a ListBox or a ComboBox?

Comment: I am using comboBox in windowsform

Comment: ComboBox.Items is not available to you?